# Create additional records and fill forward with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+-----+
|    | name  | max |
+----+-------+-----+
| 0  | a     | 1   |
| 1  | b     | 2   |
| 2  | c     | 2   |
| 3  | d     | 4   |
| 4  | e     | 1   |
+----+-------+-----+
```

The column `name` represents an item name, while the column `max` represents the maximum group number that name is a part of. With the way this data is provided, an item belongs not only to that maximum group, but also to every group less than that number as well.

I want to "explode" this dataframe to create additional records for each name and count down max to the value `1` within a new column.

Ultimately, I want my new dataframe to look like this:

```
+----+-------+------+--------+
|    | name  | max  | number |
+----+-------+------+--------+
| 0  | a     | 1    | 1      |
| 1  | b     | 2    | 2      |
| 2  | b     | 2    | 1      |
| 3  | c     | 2    | 2      |
| 4  | c     | 2    | 1      |
| 5  | d     | 4    | 4      |
| 6  | d     | 4    | 3      |
| 7  | d     | 4    | 2      |
| 8  | d     | 4    | 1      |
| 9  | e     | 1    | 1      |
+----+-------+------+--------+
```

I was thinking about using the function `df.ffill()`, but that only fills in `NaN`, and I need to first create the `NaN` rows.  I was also thinking about using `df.groupby()`, but I'm not sure if that's the right direction either.

I could think so a way to do this with something like a nested `for-loop`, but I'd rather not iterate over a dataframe.

Comment: Would you ever have to worry about a different group with the same name later on?  Could you have a b c d e b?

Comment: No tin this situation.  In fact, `name` is actually the index, but I used `reset_index()` prior to this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My variant would be:

```
df2 = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(df["max"])).reset_index(drop=True)
df2["number"] = df2.groupby("name").cumcount(ascending=False) + 1
```

which gives

```
In [137]: df2
Out[137]: 
  name  max  number
0    a    1       1
1    b    2       2
2    b    2       1
3    c    2       2
4    c    2       1
5    d    4       4
6    d    4       3
7    d    4       2
8    d    4       1
9    e    1       1
```

It does assume that the original indices are unique to make the repeat operation concise.  If needed, we could replace with

```
df2 = df.iloc[np.repeat(range(len(df)), df["max"])].reset_index(drop=True)
```

or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can reindex the dataframe with cumulative sum of 'max' column w.r.t that impute the rows, fill the rows with 'bfill' in 'name' column and groped decrement order in 'max' column

```
df.index = df['max'].cumsum()-1
df = df.reindex(pd.RangeIndex(df.index.max() + 1)).bfill()
df = df.groupby(['name']).apply(lambda x: x['max'] - np.arange(len(x))).reset_index().drop(['level_1'],axis=1)
```

Out:

```
  name  max
0   a   1.0
1   b   2.0
2   b   1.0
3   c   2.0
4   c   1.0
5   d   4.0
6   d   3.0
7   d   2.0
8   d   1.0
9   e   1.0
```